# V2 API - Not enough permissions to access

Tags: api, permissions, linkedin-api

Unable to share after being issued with an access token for w_share

{"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Not enough permissions to access: POST /ugcPosts","status":403}

Unable to request permissions for w_member_social w_organization_social r_member_social r_organization_social OAuth flow just redirects to redirect uri provided without displaying LinkedIn login, no code is provided on redirect either. There is no mention that you need to be a partner to access the V2 API and as of March, there is no option to continue using V1.

Do you now need to be a partner to access the V2 API?

Answer (score 1):

for r_liteprofile (replaces r_basicprofile) , r_emailaddress, w_member_social (replaces w_share)
not need partner any other you have to apply for partnership program
till March 1st you can use V1 after that that will not available

check this  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context

Comment: Using the permissions suggested and following the migration doc, I now receive a new error 

error=unauthorized_scope_error&error_description=Scope+%26quot%3Br_liteprofile%26quot%3B+is+not+authorized+for+your+application

I'm being told that the use of the r_liteprofile is not authorised? When I remove this permission I receive the same error but for w_member_social.

Comment: authorization and Generate an Access Token working correct ? you are getting problem in sharing I mean in using w_member_social

Comment: Authorisation and generate token only work with legacy scopes, any attempt to use the new scopes fails to bring up LinkedIn login and redirect to the supplied redirect url without a code.

Auth url I'm using: 


$"https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id={clientId}&redirect_uri={callbacklUrl}&state={client.Id}&scope=r_emailaddress w_member_social"

Comment: Go at Linkedin check @MyApp
Default Application Permissions
check these permission is listed there or not

Comment: When I check my LinkedIn app default permissions only legacy permissions are available for selection.

Comment: I am also facing similar issue with permission for V2 APIs. There isn't any permission named "r_liteprofile" in default permissions list for App. Please share if you found solution.

Comment: @MansiShah Shah if you have created new app then that will come with old permission 
if you have old app then all new basic permission should be there.
check this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context